# split nested list of dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to separate a list of nested dictionaries.  If you notice below, the first nest is combined

```
names = [{'firstname': [{'firstname': 'john', 'lastname': 'smith'},{'firstname': 'mary', 'lastname': 'smith'}], 'lastname': 'smith'}, 
{'firstname': 'henry', 'lastname': 'ford'},
{'firstname': 'henry', 'lastname': 'adams'} ]
```

Is there a way to split them to:

```
names2 =[{'firstname':'john', 'lastname':'smith'}, {'firstname':'mary', 'lastname':'smith'}, {'firstname':'henry', 'lastname':'ford'}, {'firstname':'henry', 'lastname':'adams'}]
```

I looked in stackoverflow but there was no consistent key printed, it is always random values.

I tried this

```
names2 = []
    for idxA in names:
        for idxB in idxA:
            names2.append(idxB)
```

but it only printed firstname and lastname without the values

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check what kind of data is in "firstname" and handle it accordingly.

```
names2 = []
for dct in names:
    if isinstance(dct["firstname"], str):
        names2.append(dct)
    else:
        names2.extend(dct["firstname"])
```

Comment: pay attention to double parenthesis at the end of the else statement. fix it, otherwise it won't compile

Comment: Fixed the typo. Thanks.